# how to present map with list as values in broadleaf

Tags: spring-mvc, broadleaf-commerce

I have map with key as string and value as list. and would like to present this in my admin page in broadleaf.

```
protected Map<String, List<SkuStoneDetails>> skuStoneDetails = new HashMap<String, List<SkuStoneDetails>>();
```

Previously i had map with key as string and value as object like below.

```
    protected Map<String, SkuStoneDetails> skuStoneDetails = new HashMap<String,<SkuStoneDetails>();
```

For that i have given admin presentation like below.

```
    @AdminPresentationMap(friendlyName = "Sku StoneDetails",
    tab = ProductImpl.Presentation.Tab.Name.Stone_Details, tabOrder = ProductImpl.Presentation.Tab.Order.SkuStoneDetails,
        //tab = Presentation.Tab.Name.Advanced, tabOrder = Presentation.Tab.Order.Advanced,
        //group = ProductImpl.Presentation.Group.Name.RPPrice, groupOrder = ProductImpl.Presentation.Group.Order.RPPrice,
    keyPropertyFriendlyName = "Sku StoneDetails Key",
    deleteEntityUponRemove = true,
    mediaField = "stoneType",
    forceFreeFormKeys = true
)
```

I have no idea of how to do this with values as list in a map.Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a Map with a List for the values is not something that we currently support in Broadleaf via @AdminPresentationMap. Feel free to open a new feature request at https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/BroadleafCommerce/issues.

I think your best bet is to do it as you had it previously. Or, you could do something like this:

```
public class SkuStone {
    @Column(name = "KEY")
    @AdminPresentation(friendlyNmae = "Sku StoneDetails Key")
    protected String key

    @OneToMany
    @AdminPresentationCollection(friendlyName = "Sku Stone Details")
    protected List<SkuStoneDetails> details = new ArrayList<SkuStoneDetails>();
}
```

And then in place of `protected Map<String, List<SkuStoneDetails>> skuStoneDetails = new HashMap<String, List<SkuStoneDetails>>();`

```
@AdminPresentationCollection()
protected List<SkuStone> stones = new ArrayList<SkuStone>();
```

Comment: Thanks i got it working this way.it would be better if you make map with list . i will create an issue to open a new feature at the given url..